# Showing a messagebox the moment the user clicks out of the textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have currently set it up such that when a button is pressed and the textbox value is incorrect, it shows a messagebox. It is ok when I am testing only one textbox but when I want to test more than 1 textbox, it becomes messy where multiple messageboxes starts appearing.

Is there a way I can set it up such that the messagebox flashes the moment the user clicks away from the textbox.

For example I am expecting the textbox text to be 'World' and the user fills in the textbox with the text  "hello". After that, the use goes on to click into the next textbox. When he does that the messagebox appears.

I have conflicting thoughts on this cos user could click 'x' on the messagebox and go to click  the 3rd textbox which will prompt the messagebox again causing annoyance. Would be great if I could get some advice on maybe a better way to do this.

In total I am having 3 textboxes all needing to be filled and I want to check if there is any invalid entry for each of them. I tried touchleave event but it is not working. Thanks for help.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    name = textbox_Name.Text;
    if (name != "World")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry for name.");
    }
    age = textbox_age.Text;
    if (age != "World")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry for age.");
    }
    gender = textbox_gender.Text;
    if (gender != "World")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry for gender.");
    }          
}
```

Comment: if this is a web app look at the onBlur event or see if there is a onLeave or onExit event for that particular control `basically when losing focus`

Comment: Think about highlighting the textboxes on "TextChanged" instead.  I like to make them red until the entered value is valid.

MessageBoxes are really only good for interrupting the user in my opinion.  However, if you want to do this, maybe concatenate all your errors in one string then show it, or use else if's and only show the most important.

Comment: From a usability perspective the approach sounds a bit intrusive. How about on leaving/changing the input it is highlighted red and a tooltip appears. The user can then move onto different inputs, but the highlight and tooltip will remain until the validation passes. Something like http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/26176?

Comment: also if the entry is invalid position the cursor to the TextBox by setting Focus() to the control as well

Comment: @WaynePincence You mean like create 3 events for each textbox and run the check inside that method and change the box to red if incorrect information instead of messageboxes? and maybe a single messagebox upon button click to alert to take note of red highlights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the logic to something that only produces one message box when the button is clicked. You could display the issue with the input in that box, maybe if name and age are wrong you could list both problems. It just requires some extra logic somewhere. I don't know what logic you need, but below is a simple example that shows a non-specific validation error.

```
      private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
            name = textbox_Name.Text;
            age = textbox_age.Text;
            gender = textbox_gender.Text;
            if (gender != "World" || name != "World" || age!="World" )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry.");
            }         
       }
```

As far as the TextChanged event goes, I'd recommend highlighting it on TextChanged, as suggested in a comment above. It's less annoying for your users. Then you could show a single MessageBox if the user clicks the button to let them know they need to fix the red textboxes.

Comment: I did thought of this but this is going to produce quite a list for the string to appear on the messagebox. message for name, message for name + age, message for name + age + gender, message for name + gender and on and on.

Comment: good answer but read the entire OP requirement / question include TextChanged event and I will up vote

Comment: utilize the `string.Join()` Method to get a better formatted MessageBox message Display

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be a validation of the setter.

```
    public string name 

    { get; 
        set
        {
            if (value != "Hello")
                MessageBox.Show("Blah");
            else
            { name = value; }
        }
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = textbox_Name.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using TextBox.LostFocus this way you can check each textbox after programmatically.

```
name = textbox_Name.Text;
age = textbox_age.Text;
gender = textbox_gender.Text;

textbox_Name.LostFocus+=delegate
{
   if (name != "World")
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry for name.");
   }
}; 
textbox_age.LostFocus+=delegate
{
   if (age != "World")
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry for age.");
   }
};
textbox_gender.LostFocus+=delegate
{
   if (gender != "World")
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry for gender.");
   }          
};
```